# Resize ComboBox in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, combobox

I'm trying to resize a combobox in a visual studio 2008.

Wwhen I try this in c# the combobox height stays locked at the default size. The only way to change it is to write code that assigns new height values at runtime.

[image: See example]

Whenever I enter a value in the height field the value changes back to 21.

This problem only occurs with comboboxes. Resizing textboxes and buttons works fine.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem with ComboBox in VS2010. I solved it by editing its DrawMode to **OwnerDrawFixed** and then changing **ItemHeight** property. Hope it will work for you also.
You can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drawmode.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Simply Change the `Font Size` of the ComboBox in the property window that will automatically increase the Height of your ComboBox.

Comment: Thanks. This works to make the font show fully in every scenario, so I may end up using this, allthough it forces me to use that value on other screen elements as well...